# Circular Floating Menu Builder error

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

( Im New in Android ) 
Im trying to add the Circular Floating Menu but for a reason i ignore the word Builder is in red.

i have this error: 
Cannot resolve symbol 'Builder'
// this word  Builder in ( SubActionButton.Builder(this); ) is in red .

Thank you for your Help

```
// Create an icon
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
        icon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .setContentView(icon)
                .build();
        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
        // repeat many times:
        ImageView itemIcon1 = new ImageView(this);
        itemIcon1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        ImageView itemIcon2 = new ImageView(this);
        itemIcon2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        ImageView itemIcon3 = new ImageView(this);
        itemIcon3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon1).build();
        SubActionButton button2 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon2).build();
        SubActionButton button3 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon3).build();

        //attach the sub buttons to the main button
        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
                .addSubActionView(button1)
                .addSubActionView(button2)
                .addSubActionView(button3)
                .attachTo(actionButton)
                .build();
```

Comment: Are you using an external library for the circular floating menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the `FloatingActionButton` that you're using is the support library native **Android** which doesn't have `.Builder()`, so you should use the **CircularFloatingMenu's** `FloatingActionButton` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This error has come because you have copy/pasted the code and by default `FloatingActionButton` is from material design library which does not have any Builder.

```
To resolve this just remove this line and start typing Floating ActionButton and in suggestions select library you are using
```

I am assuming you are  using **OGUZDEV** library for CIRCULAR FAB. I am attaching Image for easy understanding. I am sure it will work. Have a nice day :)[image]